# Tracking plays with audio.js and analytics in ruby

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, analytics

I'm a beginner/amateur ruby developer working on an app for users to upload audio files.

I'm looking for the best way to track and display plays in the users profile.

Any help would be appreciated..

Comment: Sorry, Stackoverflow is a Q&A site, not a tech suport site. What you are trying is a more complex undertaking than could be answered in here. Google for how to play audio file, on how to upload in ruby and try to implement that. If it does not work, come back with concrete questions.

Comment: Johannes, thanks for the quick reply. I already have a login system, with upload and playing the files on the audio.js player. I'm looking for someone to point me in the direction to track plays on individual files and display that data (the information about plays only related to the users uploaded files.)

Comment: Then please formulate a clear technical question on a problem where we can help. And upload relevant source code that we need to know to help. As the question is currently written, I have no idea if you want HTML/CSS help,would like database help to persist plays or need help with the communication between frontend and backend.

Answer (score 0):

Audio.js has nice [documentation](https://kolber.github.io/audiojs/docs/). Don't be shy and feel free to read it.

About your question: You can execute ajax request to your backend each time when audio track ends. Just override this method:

```
  trackEnded: function(e) {},
```